# SharePoint MySite - Purge newsfeed activity?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint

After setting up User Profile sync with AD I've noticed that the newsfeed section of each user's MySite is now flooded with lots of random notes detailing changes that have been pulled in about their (and their contacts') profiles.

Is there anyway to purge this activity and stop updates from the sync service getting listed on the newsfeed?  Our users are likely to find it strange getting updates about changes to their own profiles that they didn't make themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262500.aspx), you can disable the `Activity Feed` timer job to disable the news feed. To clean out the data, you run the `Activity Feed Clean up` timer job.